# How to create a type that requires some properties but tolerates any additional properties?

Tags: typescript

I have a util function whose first parameter `param` must include (simplified for example) the properties `param.X` and `param.Y`, but it doesn't matter what other properties it has. For instance it can also have `param.Z` but that's not used by the util function and can be ignored.

How can I type the param such that it enforces this constraint without complaining something like `ParamType does not include property Z`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intersect the object type with `Record<PropertyKey, unknown>`.

```
const fn = (obj: { x: string; y: string } & Record<PropertyKey, unknown>) => {
};

fn({x: 'x'}) // Fails
fn({x: 'x', y: 'y'}) // Passes
fn({x: 'x', y: 'y', z: 'z'}) // Passes
```

Comment: From where I'm standing that is some seriously advanced Typescript trickery, but it works exactly as I wanted! Thanks! Would you mind adding an explanation of this for us amateurs?

Comment: `&` intersects two types. Eg `{ foo: string } & { bar: string }` results in a type of `{ foo: string; bar: string }`. Then, `Record<keyof any, unknown>` can represent any object.

Comment: That second part is the part I didn't grasp, `&` at least I already knew :) Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `keyof any`, is better to use `PropertyKey`.

Comment: `PropertyKey` isn't documented that properly I think.. That's why a lot of people misses it, including me.

Answer (score 1):

There is already an answer(more granular), this one is only to show just another way(syntactically)...

```ts
type SomeRequired = {
  x: string,
  y: string,
  [key: PropertyKey]: unknown   //<--- type PropertyKey = string | number | symbol. A mapped type to accomodate additional non-required properties. We can constrain the 'unknown' here depending upon the context of use.
}

function applyFn(input: SomeRequired): void {

}

applyFn({}); // <-- Error, missing all required properties
applyFn({x: "1"}); // <-- Error, missing some of the required properties
applyFn({x: "1", y: "2"}); // <-- Ok, at least all required properties are there
applyFn({x: "1", y:"2", z: "3", p: { a: 1 }}); // Ok, additional properties along with the required ones
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Partial<ParamType>`. This allows you to specify only a subset of the type.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype

Comment: Hm, I think that will set all the fields in the type to optional, whereas I specifically want a subset of the fields to be mandatory.